# Get file content from github repo on specified line number(s)

Tags: github, github-api

### Question

I am wondering if there is a way to get the content of a file on a github repo with specified line number(s) through GitHub APIs. I know that it is possible to generate a permanent link to a code snippet from the github UI as follows

`https://github.com/<org_name>/<repo_name>/blob/master/<path_to_file>#L{Start}-L{End}`

[image: Screenshot]

However I cant seem to find a way to get the content of a file **on a specific line number(s)** through their [Github APIs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest). I tried the [Search API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-on-github) but couldnt find anything useful. Any help on that is greatly appreciated!

### Use Case

I am creating a tutorials application and I would like to query lines of code to generate dynamic code snippets from a file hosted on github.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution?

Comment: Hey @CelsoFrança ! I was able to fetch the content of the github file using this API and store it in a variable

`https://api.github.com/repos/${orgName}/${repoName}/contents/${file}?ref=${ref}` and then with some logic, I spliced the content using a `getSlice(content,range)` function through which I use a `slice` and `join` methods for string manipulation. Let me know if this helps! Or if you found another way...

Comment: I wrote a quick blog post tutorial for this https://dev.to/tweettamimi/how-to-query-specific-line-s-from-a-file-using-github-apis-ckl

Comment: Thank you @TamimiAhmad! I've just used Python request to get the source code file and then retrieve the desired lines.